# Where is the Panoramas folder in iOS 7.0.4 when browsing for it with iFiles?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, panorama

I'm attempting to move a large image into the Panoramas folder of my iPad Mini.  I can find the image in iFile which is located at `var/mobile/Media/DCIM/Apple100/`, and the image I want to copy/move is titled `IMG_0152.JPG` and is 1600px wide x 800px tall (or simply 1600x800).

Obviously, the image is way too large to be used as a normal wallpaper on my iPad, so I'd like to move it into the Panoramas folder.  When I go into the Photos app, I can select the image I want to copy/move, but moving it into the Panoramas folder is not allowable.

If I can access the folder via iFile, I'm pretty sure I'll be able to copy the image into it that way as a backdoor.

If there's another way to do this by using an iPhone/iPad/iPod explorer on OS X, please let me know and I'll try to do it that way instead.

Additionally, if its possible to do this with iPhoto and iTunes, I'd like to know how to do that as well.

If you could point me in the right direction, I'd be extremely grateful.

Thanks very much, I appreciate any input you can provide me!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple removed the panoramic background feature in the final release of iOS 7.

> Sources: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/09/ios-7-panoramic-wallpapers-removed.html
>   http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-panoramic-photo-as-live-wallpaper-ios-7-your-iphone-0147395/